# Contador para division en html y javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo dentro de mi codigo unas variables que pueden recibir solo 0 o 1, dentro de las cuales se utilizan para crear (o no) un campo (input number) para digitar numeros.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$variable1 = 1;
$variable2 = 1;
$variable3 = 1;
?>
                <div id="numberss"><?php
                        if($variable1 > 0){?>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numero1" name="numero1" value="" required><?php
                        }else{?>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numero1" name="numero1" value="0" readonly><?php
                        }
                            if($variable2 > 0){?>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numero2" name="numero2" value="" required><?php
                         }else{?>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numero2" name="numero2" value="0" readonly><?php
                         }
                            if($variable3 > 0){?>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numero3" name="numero3" value="" required><?php
                            }else{?>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numero3" name="numero3" value="0" readonly><?php
                            }?>
                                <label><strong> PROMEDIO </strong></label>
                                <input id="ind_promedio" name="ind_promedio" class="form-control" value="" readonly>
                </div>

<script>
        //Suma automatica mediante queryselector
        const container = document.querySelector('#numberss');
        const inputs = container.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
        const result = document.querySelector('#ind_promedio');

        container.addEventListener('change', handleChange, false);

        function handleChange() {
            let total = 0;
            inputs.forEach(input => total += Number(input.value));
            result.value = total/3;
        }
</script>
```

En este caso el codigo va a correr con normalidad y me va a sacar un promedio entre los 3 INPUTS ya que todas las variables estan en 1, pero en tal caso de que 1 de las variables este en 0 pasa el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podria indicarle al script que hay allí abajo que divida dependiendo de la cantidad de inputs que cumplan la condicion de la variable?

Muchas gracias de antemano, alguna corrección o alguna recomendación es bienvenida, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes aplicar un `filter` y usar su `length` para saber cuántas cumplen con la condición.

```
result.value = total / inputs.filter(input => parseInt(input.value) > 0).length;
```

Comment: Hola compañero, gracias por tu respuesta, perdona mi ignorancia, a la hora de reemplazar `result.value = total/3;` por tu codigo: `result.value = total / inputs.filter(input => input.value > 0).length;` no me muestra ahora el promedio, ¿Me hara falta algo mas?

Comment: @Decox faltó convertir a número. Ya actualizé la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Lo he logrado con bases que me ha dado @Fedex7501 , he modificado unicamente el script de la siguiente forma:

```
<script>
    //Suma automatica mediante queryselector
    const container = document.querySelector('#numberss');
    const inputs = container.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
    const result = document.querySelector('#ind_promedio');

    container.addEventListener('change', handleChange, false);

    function handleChange() {
        let total = 0;
        let total2 = 0;
        inputs.forEach(input => total += Number(input.value)); //Contador de la suma, independiente de cuantos hayan
        inputs.forEach(input => total2 += Number(input.value > 0)); //Contador de los que se insertan con mas de un valor de 0, para dividir con este resultado
        result.value = total / total2;
    }
```